# access hbase table fron hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to access hbase table from hadoop mapreduce and I'm using windowsXP, cygwin, hadoop-0.20.2 and hbase-0.92.0.
I am able to run mapreduce wordcount successfully on 3 pcs and have verfied that hadoop and hbase are working fine.  I can also create table from shell.

I have tried many examples but they are not working, for example when I try to compile it using
javac Example.java

it gives error..... 
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client does not exist
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase does not exist 
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io does not exist

please can anyone help me in this......
-plz give me some example code to access hbase from hadoop map reduce
-also guide me how should I compile and execute it?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Please let me know when you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This website has example hbase/Mapreduce code.  I haven't tried it, but it looks OK at first glance.  Also what distribution of Hadoop/HBase are you using?  Apache?  Cloudera?

http://kdpeterson.net/blog/2009/09/minimal-hbase-mapreduce-example.html